# How to select multiple rows from a column/table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("NOTGIVEN","NOTGIVEN","NOTGIVEN");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("user_live", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_new_post ORDER BY user_date_post DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  print($row['user_full_name']);
  }
```

And instead of selecting the table/row `user_new_post` how can I be able to select individual values "users" and then print/echo them out?

Answer (score 1):

Either you have another table "user" on which you can use

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

or you can use a WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM user_new_post WHERE user_full_name like 'a%' ORDER BY user_date_post DESC
```

to get all user full name starting with 'a'

Answer (score 0):

You may perform a search for exactly a user name like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_new_post WHERE user_name= '".$user."'");
```

Or perform a regular expression in the query to search for user's name match your pattern:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_new_post WHERE user_name REGXP '".$pattern."'");
```

Or use like keywork provied by MySQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_new_post WHERE user_name like '".$user."'");
```